# How can I sort based on children?

Tags: database, postgresql, sorting, fluent, vapor

Using Vapor and Fluent (PostgreSQL if that matters) I have entity `B` that has `aID: Node` (A is B's parent) to reference `A` and `A` has a one-to-many relationship with `B`. How can I make a query to fetch all `A`'s sorted by the count of `B`'s?

I want the result to look something like this:

`All A's in DB`

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Hi",
    "bCount": 1000
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Another",
    "bCount": 800
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Test",
    "bCount": 30
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

1. Create a modal for A
2. Turn that JSON string to array of A

if you do this your sorting becomes as easy as -

`array.sort { $0.bCount < $1.bCount }`

Comment: Thanks, that would work. I'd rather not fetch all objects in the database and then sort. I'd rather let SQL do the sorting for me if I can do that with Fluent.

Comment: That will be more efficient considering time. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be tricky to implement entirely in Fluent using `Entity`. Firstly, you will need to use raw SQL to get your `bCount`. Secondly, you will need to change your `init(node:)` to accept `bCount`, though it shouldn't be in your `makeNode()` because we don't want to create a stored database field for it.

Try this for your raw SQL (untested):

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM B
    WHERE B.aID = A.id
  ) AS bCount
FROM A
ORDER BY bCount
```

Then, run that query to get your A models.

```
var models: [A] = []
if let driver = drop.database?.driver as? PostgreSQLDriver {
  if case .array(let array) = try driver.raw(sql) {
    for result in array {
      do {
        var model = try A(node: result)
        models.append(model)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I said before, your init method on `A` will be receiving `bCount` so you will need to store it there.